# Entity Framework execution order

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can anyone tell me if on the line which calls `CreateObjectSet` whether or not it returns the whole table and then does the Where expression (in memory) or is the where expression included in the generated SQL?

```
public virtual T GetById(int Id)
        {
            if (Id != 0)
            {

            PropertyInfo PrimaryKey = GetPrimaryKey();
            var ItemParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "item");
            var WhereExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                (Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.Property(
                        ItemParameter,
                        PrimaryKey.Name
                    ),
                    Expression.Constant(Id)
                ),
                new[] { ItemParameter }
                );


            T Entity = GetObjectContext().CreateObjectSet<T>().Where(WhereExpression).SingleOrDefault<T>();
            GetObjectContext().Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, Entity);

            return Entity;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`CreateObjectSet<T>()` returns an instance of the type `ObjectSet<T>` and this class implements `IQueryable<T>`. Methods called on `IQueryable` will be translated to SQL.

You are calling `IQueryable<T>.Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)`.

So the condition is applied to your database and only at most two rows will be fetched, not the entire table.